# Changing/Modifying Magento 2 Rest Api call from url

Tags: api, product-list, geturl, magento-2.0.5

I want to use magento2 rest api of products to get list of details of products based on some criteria. For example -

http://localhost:8080/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-06-01 10:38:52&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&fields=items[id,sku,name,price,created_at,updated_at,custom_attributes]

Above url get list of products whose updated date is after or equal to 2016-06-01 10:38:52.
Here is the small part of sample output -

```
"items": [
    {
      "id": 54,
      "sku": "MH01-XS-Orange",
      "name": "Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie-XS-Orange",
      "price": 52,
      "created_at": "2016-06-01 10:38:52",
      "updated_at": "2016-06-01 10:38:52",
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "description",
          "value": "<p>Ideal for cold-weather training or work outdoors, the Chaz Hoodie promises superior warmth with every wear. Thick material blocks out the wind as ribbed cuffs and bottom band seal in body heat.</p>\n<p>&bull; Two-tone gray heather hoodie.<br />&bull; Drawstring-adjustable hood. <br />&bull; Machine wash/dry.</p>"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "image",
          "value": "/m/h/mh01-orange_main.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "small_image",
          "value": "/m/h/mh01-orange_main.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
          "value": "/m/h/mh01-orange_main.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "color",
          "value": "56"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "options_container",
          "value": "container2"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "required_options",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "has_options",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "url_key",
          "value": "chaz-kangeroo-hoodie-xs-orange"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "size",
          "value": "167"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I want to filter the output by some attribute code. for example i want to get Products with particular color , products with particular materials.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use url like below change with your attribute code and it's value

> http://mcs.com/beta/pmagento2/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=First%20Product%20test%20work&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=price&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10&fields=items[id,sku,name,price,created_at,updated_at,custom_attributes]

Comment: can we use multiple filters in this url, for example products of price =52 and color =red

Comment: I have updated answer check it

Comment: what is First%20Product%20test%20work

Comment: This is product name  "FIrst Product test Work"